# Cant get model working for submit and validation on the show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on a project and im very new to rails,

I can't figure out what is wrong exectly.
I get this error.

NoMethodError in Products#index

uninitialized constant ProductsController::Offer

Esentially I have a feature im trying to implement.

in my products table I have a column called reserve price, I want a userto submit a number on the form on the products page which then validates it againts the reserve price, if accepted it gets added to cart , if not flash please enter higher offer,

the problem is I just can't seem to figure out how to get the model and controllers to work in tandem.

Iv'e been at this all week and I still don't have a clue.

I wondered if anyone could look at my code and see what im missing as for the view page I am getting the error that the undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class and I was sure I inputed the right model for the form, if I can get that working I can get the rest done quick but I dunno what im missing.

offer controller.rb
    class OffersController < ApplicationController

attr_accessible :product, :offer , :reserve_price

def new
  @offer = Offer.new
  end

```
end
```

offer model.rb

```
   class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
```

belongs_to :product
  has_many :reserve_prices

attr_accessible :product, :offer , :reserve_price

validates_presence_of :offer
  validate :ensure_meets_reserve_price

private
  def ensure_meets_reserve_price
    if amount < self.product.reserve_price
      errors.add(:amount, "does not meet reserve price")
    end
  end

private
  def reserve_price
     product.reserve_price
  end

def your_offer
    @your_offer = Offer.new

end

def new
    @offer = Offer.new = :your_offer
  end

```
 end
```

Products index view file

```
   class ProductsController < ApplicationController
```

before_filter :authenticate, :except => [:index, :show]

# GET /products
  # GET /products.xml

def index
    @offer = Offer.new

```
@products = Product.search(params[:search_query])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @products }
end
```

end

# GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.xml
  def show

```
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])


respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @product }
end
```

end

# GET /products/new
  # GET /products/new.xml
  def new
    @product = Product.new

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @product }
end
```

end

# GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

# POST /products
  # POST /products.xml
  def create
    @product = current_user.products.new(params[:product])

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @product.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@product, :notice => 'Product was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @product, :status => :created, :location => @product }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @product.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

# PUT /products/1
  # PUT /products/1.xml
  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
    format.html { redirect_to(@product, :notice => 'Product was successfully updated.') }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @product.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

# DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.xml
  def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to(products_url) }
  format.xml  { head :ok }
end
```

end
end

Products controller.rb

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :except => [:index, :show]

  # GET /products
  # GET /products.xml
  def index
    @products = Product.search(params[:search_query])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @products }
    end
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.xml
  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @product }
    end
  end

  # GET /products/new
  # GET /products/new.xml
  def new
    @product = Product.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @product }
    end
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.xml
  def create
    @product = current_user.products.new(params[:product])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@product, :notice => 'Product was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @product, :status => :created, :location => @product }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @product.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
 # PUT /products/1
 # PUT /products/1.xml
 def update
   @product = Product.find(params[:id])

   respond_to do |format|
     if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
       format.html { redirect_to(@product, :notice => 'Product was successfully updated.') }
       format.xml  { head :ok }
     else
       format.html { render :action => "edit" }
       format.xml  { render :xml => @product.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end

 # DELETE /products/1
 # DELETE /products/1.xml
 def destroy
   @product = Product.find(params[:id])
   @product.destroy

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to(products_url) }
     format.xml  { head :ok }
   end
 end
       end
```

any help?

much appricated ive been at this a while and have not figured it out!

Comment: to which action does your view belongs to?

Comment: the view is a products index view, i just pasted the form_for its self as its not linking up which is my first problem :)

Comment: you need to use nested resources, can you post your products controller?

Comment: Done :) Your help is very much appicated

Comment: your code need some fixes. Like `belongs_to :product
  has_many :reserve_prices` instead of `belongs_to :products
  has_many :reserve_price`. And that 2 last private methods in Offer model are strange.

Comment: thanks any suggestions instead?

Comment: I suggest you to go through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html there is all you need.

Comment: ill check that out now, ive got alot of great and complex features in my project working but i just cant seem to figure this out as i know whats happening but not execlty what error im making, i just finsihed the whole of agile rails 3!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly:

- the error shows when accessing products#show
- you want to include an offer form in the product#show page

In that case, you need to initialize the @offer variable in the ProductsController show action like so:

```
@offer = Offer.new
```

ADDITION

to next Problem: ProductsController::Offer is unknown, which it should not be as you have a Offer model. I've just tried including your Offer form into a show action, and it rendered it ok, apart from that you initialize the field with a new instance of Offer. (maybe an amount rather?). Anyway, I can't see from your code snippets why the Offer model is not available in your controller. can you provide the complete source?

I first suspected your strange private methods in Offer

```
 def your_offer
     @your_offer = Offer.new

   end

def new
  @offer = Offer.new = :your_offer
end
```

to be the cause, but I've included them and the form renders fine. But I what the heck are they supposed to do?

Comment: yes the page will not show with the form in it, when i updated the product contoller i still got this NoMethodError in Products#index


undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Comment: sorry i think i chaged the wrong one :) i put that in the show and index for product and now im getting a different error, so progress :) its uninitialized constant ProductsController::Offer

Comment: well, I guess that's a new question, then, if I've answered your question it would be nice if you accepted it. And as for the new question: The first thing you should do is reading the error message carefully to find out where the error was thrown (file, line number...) - maybe you find the answer yourself then, and if not, provide this information with the question.

Comment: well my question is I can't get the form working. it is vague but with a few  problems I can't help it.  :) will do

Comment: esentially the user puts in a price and submits it and it is validated againts a reserve price column in the products table, if it gets accepted it gets added to card if not, try a higher offer etc, Ill post the rest now, i do appricate your help, also i have the full offer model here. is there anything else you are missing?

Comment: I haven't seen anything in Offer. You have to find out why Offer isn't available in your ProductsController, if that's still the current issue.

Comment: NameError in ProductsController#index

uninitialized constant ProductsController::Offer

Rails.root: C:/Users/Paul/Desktop/ipay final
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/products_controller.rb:12:in `index'

Comment: I give up now, sorry. I've already guessed that it happens in the ProductsController, as stated above, but without seeing the source there is no use in spending my time guessing where your Errors come from. You will have to work through them step by step, or, probably better, work through a tutorial so that you can get an idea how this might work and then come back with questions.

Comment: no problem bento, thank you for your help so far, pure gentle man. before you go file were you trying to see as i updated them for you and must have put up the wrong file by accident.